# How to fix python SpeechRecognition In Python On Rasp/Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I have had a play round with code and grabbed some code of other developers. I have this code which keeps printing the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ImportError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/SHADOW/tkinter.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I have tried plugging in some headphones with a mic but I have no idea what the problem is. Do i have to uninstall it then re-install it?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said {}".format(text))

    except:
        print("sorry")
```

Comment: Here are some instructions on how to install `pyaudio`: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: @mypetlion I have just tried that but has not worked

Comment: Possibly  because if you followed the above instructions you installed it for python 2 and you're using python 3. To install for python 3: `python3 -m pip install pyaudio`

Comment: It was definatley python 3

Comment: Has not worked in what way?